# Css changes reflect only after deploy command in magento2

Tags: magento2

Now i have created custom theme in magento2.Every time i wrote css it doesn't reflect immediately.I have changed mode to "developer".And also disable cache
in backend.I have given the following commands to reflect my custom css.

**rm -f var/* -R**

**rm -f pub/static -R**

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

**chmod 0777 var -R**

**chmod 0777 pub/static -R**

It takes too much time to do my design work.So please anyone help on this.

Answer (score 3):

The solution suggested by [Emizen Tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6333615/emizen-tech) works fine and helps me out to resolve the same issue in my site.

However, it only requires `mode` to be set to the developer.

In order to change the `mode`, here is the command:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: Nicely written buddy. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

you can just write css/js for theme in the app/design same folder

to reflect the changes just remove that deployed file in pub/static folder

Magento2 will auto create the missing/deleted static files

Make sure that **pub/static/.htaccess** should be there for auto generation of Static Files. 
as I can See you have removed the all files and folder into **pub/staic** folder

copy this **.htaccess** file form Magento's GIT Repo.  : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess

Comment: "Magento2 will auto create the missing/deleted static files" ONLY IN DEVELOPER MODE!!!

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to directly change in pub/static folder and then it complete put this change in app/design folder that make it faster.